# What is this regex doing and the method of replacements within arrays

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I think I know what the below is doing, but not wanting to make any assumptions wanted to make sure..

RegEx is:

```
$value = preg_replace(array('/[^a-z0-9_ -]/', '/[ -]+/', '/^-|-$/'), array('', '-', ''), $str);
```

First part in the array is simple, replaces anything but a-z, 0-9, underscore, space and a hyphen with nothing. Though shouldn't the hyphen after the space be escaped?

Second part I'm not so sure.... I assume it's saying replace one or more spaces OR one or more hyphens with a single hyphen? Am I right? But again, escape the hyphen?

Third part is a little confusing..... isn't the `|` character in regex the `OR` operator? So replace a hyphen or a hyphen with nothing? If the `|` was escaped then I would read it as the whole string would need to match `-|-` and replace it with nothing?

Lastly..... am I correct in my thinking that it handles the replacements in the position it gets them? So it would handle the first spot in the array first and then move onto the second and third with what's left of the string; so if the first replacement for example replaces something, then the second replacement will work on the revised version of the string?

Comment: Hyphen doesn't need to be escaped since it's at the end of a character class (`[]`) - If it's at the beginning or the end, it doesn't need to be escaped.

Comment: Looks like regex for creating slugs.

Comment: @acheong87 yeah it is part of it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the first replacement, the string will only have letters, numbers, spaces, underscores, and hyphens.  The second replacement will turn all consecutive spaces and/or hyphens into a single hyphen, and the third replacement will remove a hyphen from the beginning or the end of the string.

Other comments:

- You do not need to escape hyphens in character classes if you put them at the beginning or end of the character class.
- The third regex `/^-|-$/` has the anchors `^` and `$`, which mean beginning of string and end of string, respectively, so this regex will match a single hyphen but only if it is at the beginning or end of the string.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks! Would I be able to replace the second one with `/[\s-]+/` instead to capture tabs as well?

Comment: @Brett Yes using `\s` would be fine, but if don't want to also capture line breaks you should use `/[ \t-]+/`.

Answer (score 1):

The hyphen does not need to be escaped if it's at the end or the beginning of the string.

The second part matches any consecutive string of spaces or hypens (even if they are mixed).

The third part matches a hyphen that is either at the start of the string (`^-`) or one that is at the end of the string (`-$`).

What this does all taken together is remove all characters that are neither letters, digits, underscores, spaces or hyphens. Then contract all consecutive spaces and hyphens to one hyphen. And lastly remove leading or trailing hyphens.

Answer (score 0):

1. Remove everything else than alphanumeric characters, space, `_` or `-`
2. Replace consecutive space or `-` by only one `-`
3. Remove leading and trailing `-`

As @nickb said the hyphen doesn't need escaping as long as it's not in a group of characters delimited by `[]`